# Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain MacOS

Tags: react-native

JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain Could not install the app on the
>   device, read the error above for details. Make sure you have an
>   Android emulator running or a device connected and have set up your
>   Android development environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDNZC.png)

Comment: Try to run adb devices in ur terminal and see if theres a device (emulator device) connected

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept and vote up an answer for further references.

Answer (score 0):

1. install the `react-native-cli` again via:

`npm i -g react-native-cli` or `yarn global add react-native-cli`

2. Recreate the project and build via:

`react-native init NAME`